# gmaps4rails zoom in on marker on user link click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I have several markers on one map, I also have several links and I want the user to be able to click the link and the map zooms in on the corresponding marker. I want to do this with a jQuery function. I browsed through the source code for gmaps4rails and found references to center_longitude and center_latitude. However using them as Gmaps.map.map.centerLongitude(12) or Gmaps.map.map.center_longitude(12) doesn't work.

What would the correct function be for dynamically changing where and how much it zooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `panTo` defined [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map).

Usage:

```
Gmaps.map.map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

Btw, `Gmaps.map.map.center_*`is dedicated to map initialization.

Comment: Cheers for the quick reply, that's indeed what I was looking for :)